# The [super dealloc] in dealloc of UIViewController giving problem in iPad

Tags: ipad, dealloc, super

I am working on an application where i am pushing one view controller on to a UINavigationController and releasing it immediately as the navigation controller retains it.When i am poping the view controller the `dealloc` method is being called as expected but the problem is the app is getting crashed.If i observe in GDB by enabling `NSZombie` its saying that `-[MyViewController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6847a00`.**If i remove `[super dealloc]`from my view controller's `dealloc`method its working just fine**.I have nothing else in dealloc method except [super dealloc].What could be the problem here, can any one please help.The code snippet is below:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
myViewController.path = selectedPath; //very important to set path here
myViewController.parentViewController = self;
[self cleanBookshelf];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:NO];
[myViewController release];
[indicatorView removeFromSuperview];
[loadingindicator stopAnimating];
```

and i am poping in one action method of myViewController as

```
-(IBAction)goBack:(UIButton*)sender{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Code please, from where you push & release the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but I suspect that the problem is with this line:

```
myViewController.parentViewController = self;
```

UIViewController's `parentViewController` property is marked `readonly`, and I'd take that as a strong message that you shouldn't mess with it.